# HTML 5 deleting last drawn shape

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am new to HTML 5 canvas, I am trying to draw a rect where the mouse is, this works fine. But I have to delete the last drawn rect. But when I delete the last drawn rect, the underlying grid is not displayed correct. I tried to add the code to jsfiddle but it won't work :(                           http://jsfiddle.net/L5YE8/    but there you can see the code and maybe help me. As said the underlying grid gets messed up when deleting the last drawn shape.

Here is my deleting part:

```
function eraseCell(cell) {
var x = (cell.column * kSizePix);
var y = (cell.row * kSizePix);

/*canvas_context.beginPath();
canvas_context.rect(x, y, kSizePix, kSizePix);
canvas_context.fillStyle = 'white';
canvas_context.fill();
canvas_context.strokeStyle = "white";
canvas_context.stroke();*/

canvas_context.clearRect(x, y, kSizePix, kSizePix);
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to "erase" by drawing a white rectangle.

That doesn't undo the last rectangle, it just paints on another white rectangle on top.

Canvas doesn't do layering, it just adds additional paint where you tell it to draw.

So if you want to draw overlapping rectangles and later erase one of them, you can:

- Save each rectangle's definition,
- Clear the entire canvas,
- Redraw all the rectangles except for the "erased" rectangle based on the saved definitions.

A typical way of saving a rectangle definition is in a javascript object:

```
var rect1 = { x:50, y:75, width:40, height:20, color:"red" };
```

You can save all the accumulated rectangles in an array as the user draws them:

```
var rectArray=[];

// add the first rectangle rectangle

rectArray.push( { x:50, y:75, width:40, height:20, color:"red" } );

// add more rectangles

rectArray.push( { x:100, y:125, width:20, height:30, color:"green" } );
rectArray.push( { x:110, y:145, width:20, height:30, color:"blue" } );
rectArray.push( { x:120, y:165, width:20, height:30, color:"purple" } );
```

Then to redraw all but the last rectangle, you can enumerate through the array an redraw each of the saved rectangles from their definition:

```
// remove the last rect definition from the array
rectArray.pop();

// clear the canvas and redraw all rects based on their saved definitions

context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

for(var i=0; i<rectArray.length; i++){
    var rect=rectArray[i];
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect( rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height );
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle=rect.color;
    context.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to what markE suggested, you can also layer multiple `<canvas>`'es  by placing them on top of each other with CSS positioning. That way you can erase parts of the top canvas with `clearRect` without having to redraw the background canvas below it.